# when i try to send sms to a diffrent number other than my registered number i am not being able to send sms (through vonage )

Tags: vonage

```
const from = "Vonage APIs";
      const to = `91${phone_number}`;
      const text = `your temporary password is : ${tempoPassword}`;

      async function sendSMS() {
        await vonage.sms
          .send({ to, from, text })
          .then((resp) => {
            console.log("Message sent successfully");
            console.log(resp);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("There was an error sending the messages.");
            console.error(err);
          });
      }
```

i want to send sms to other number . or tell me if it is hapening because of free tier if this is the case then the is the above code good for paid also

Comment: What happenings instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?